# SSIS parallel processing foreach loop

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis, parallel.foreach

I am writing an SSIS Package that reads records from one table and returns 20 SQL Servers names, the next steps that is **foreach loop** which fetches the database objects and creates a file of that db script. Even that is done with success but the question is it takes too much time that is approx. 3-4 hours to complete.

The Package flow is,

- SQL Task that returns 20 SQL servers - executing a single query
- Second is **Foreach** **Loop**, that iterates through all the object from one server and generates a file which is stored to a location.

The question is,

- Can we reduce the time from **3 to 4 hours** to a minimum?
- Is it possible to let the foreach loop execute parallel?

I am trying to divide **ONE LOOP into to THREE Loops**, that way I hope that will reduce the **3 to 4 hours** into **1 hours**

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you using SQL Server's built in mechanisms, like SQL Server Utility to run this auditing query on all servers at once? That is, if SQL Server Utility doesn't *already* collect the information you want?

Comment: I have a package and modifying that to reduce that to a minimum time. and it is been executed from SQL Agent Job weekly.

Comment: Yes it is possible to run multiple `foreach loop`s in parallel.   The rest of your question is too broad.

Comment: Yes it is broad but brief explanation is there, as there might be lot more comments to ask certain things. could you please help me with the parallel execution

Comment: I am trying SEQUENCE container and other stuffs but still no success

Comment: There is no such ability built-in but there are extensions to SSIS that offer the functionality. Parallel Loop Task by COZYROC is an example.  Pulling something written and tested from the web is likely to be both more robust and easier to implement than rolling your own.

Answer (score 4):

There is no in-built parallel foreach loop functionality in SSIS. This means you need to hand code it, in which case there are a couple of approaches:

- add ~20 tasks to the foreach loop which each process based on a different variable. This could be generated using BIML to make it easier to create and more consistent

  - create a script task which executes a child package N times. There are numerous examples of parallel execution in .net on the web.

m

Comment: I have done the same given difference variables and divided that to 3 loops in a single Sequence container but no help, it shows me running all with the GREEN and YELLOW colors, but only one loop generates the files not others.

Comment: This would need to be a foreach loop, not just a regular sequence container

Comment: yes, it is foreach loop inside the sequence contianer

Comment: I misread your comment, it seems like the other foreach loops on not configured correctly, if they do not produce output. Puts some break points in and see what the variables are set to, maybe the output files are being overwritten

Comment: I copied the same loop that already worked, and divided into two loops changing it's input values in to where conditions to provide two different inputs for testing. The variables are already changed accordingly.  For example, first loop reads server SQL1 and second SQL2 and creates the objects of that as physical files to that respective folders SQL and SQL2.